# Delete confirmation pop up, jquery,bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, popup

**Im trying to do a pop up which says("are you sure you want to delele?") and have OK - CANCEL options..**

Here is my delete button:

```
<a href='borrar.php?borrar=1&iden=".$row['id']."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>BORRAR</button></a>
```

And here is the function "delete"

```
   <?php include('connect.php'); 

    $error="";

    if(isset($_GET['borrar']))
{
        $ident=$_GET['iden'];
        $delete=mysql_query("DELETE FROM materias WHERE id=$ident");
    if($delete)
        header("location:hola.php");
        else
            $msg='ERROR : '.mysql_error();
}



?>
```

I wanna make a pop up using bootstraps and i have no idea :/.

Hope you can help me :)

Thanks!

Comment: See https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: if you want jquery popup use if(confirm(""are you sure you want to delele?""))

Comment: Can you write it please? :S

Answer (score 1):

```
You can do it by ajax also by following this code :
function deleteRecord(user_id)
{
    if(confirm('Sure To Remove This Record ?'))
     {
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'delete page name',
                data:  {user_id: user_id},
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (data) 
                {
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function(error)
                {
                }
                });

     }
}
```

In html call function like this :

```
 <button onclick="deleteRecord(<?php echo $user_id ?>);" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-power-off" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

html page may be like :
[image]

Comment: Where should i put that function dude?

Comment: But i cannot join your function with my code :/, can help me witht hat?

Comment: in between script tag like this.
<script></script>

Comment: okay, than on that delete button put this :
onclick="return confirm('Do you wish to delete?');return false;"

Comment: but i dont know how to put my html in that form:
Here is myhtml function:
<a href='borrar.php?borrar=1&iden=".$row['id']."' onclick="return confirm('are you sure you want to delele?')"><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>BORRAR</button></a>

Comment: Mate, can you please put the entire function?. I ama little dizzy:/

Comment: replace with this, i hope, it will help you :
<a href='borrar.php?borrar=1&iden=".$row['id']."' onclick="return confirm('are you sure you want to delele?');return false;"><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>BORRAR</button></a>

Answer (score 0):

A simple javascript code is

```
<a href='borrar.php?borrar=1&iden=".$row['id']."' onclick="return confirm('are you sure you want to delele?')"><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>BORRAR</button></a>
```

Comment: I put your function and my program stopped working dude :/

Comment: Please check for syntax errors on the page. Its just javascript code and cannot stop you program unless there is some syntax error.